# JQuery/JS select specific element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'd like to pick a special element with jQuery. I've tried a lot of things. I'm hoping someone can help me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  open = false;
});

// Rotate the dropdown button on click
$(".category-name").click(function() {
  if (open == false) {
    $(this).find(".fa-caret-down").fadeOut("fast");
    $(this).find(".fa-caret-up").fadeIn("fast");
    $(this).prev("li").find(".category-dropdown1").slideDown("fast");
    open = true;
  } else {
    $(this).find(".fa-caret-down").fadeIn("fast");
    $(this).find(".fa-caret-up").fadeOut("fast");
    $(this).prev("li").find(".category-dropdown1").slideUp("fast");
    open = false;
  }
})
```

```html
<ul class="sortable">
  <li class="category">
    <a class="category-name d-flex">Favoriten <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
    <ul class="category-dropdown">
        <li class="category-animation d-flex"><a href="#">Animation1</a></li>
        <li class="category-animation d-flex"><a href="#">Animation1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="category">
    <a class="category-name d-flex">Tanzen <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
    <ul class="category-dropdown">
        <li class="category-animation d-flex"><a href="#">Animation1</a></li>
        <li class="category-animation d-flex"><a href="#">Animation1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>                     
    </ul>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When I click on "**.category-name**", I want to select "**.category-dropdown**". Preferably with "(this)", so that the variability is preserved.

Comment: Make to use select box in HTML

Answer (score 5):

You have at least two options:

1. Use `$(this).next()`, since it's the next element, or
2. Use `$(this).parent().find(".category-dropdown")` to make the code slightly more resilient in the face of changes to the HTML structure

Here's an example of #1:

```js
$(".category-name").on("click", function() {
    $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
    $(this).next().addClass("highlight");
});
```

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: #ffff9a;
 }
```

```html
<ul class="sortable">
  <li class="category">
      <a class="category-name d-flex">Favoriten <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-dropdown">
          <li class="category-animation d-flex"><a href="#">Animation1</a></li>
          <li class="category-animation d-flex"><a href="#">Animation1</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="category">
      <a class="category-name d-flex">Tanzen <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-dropdown">
          <li class="category-animation d-flex"><a href="#">Animation1</a></li>
          <li class="category-animation d-flex"><a href="#">Animation1</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>                   
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here's an example of #2:

```js
$(".category-name").on("click", function() {
    $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
    $(this).parent().find(".category-dropdown").addClass("highlight");
});
```

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: #ffff9a;
 }
```

```html
<ul class="sortable">
  <li class="category">
      <a class="category-name d-flex">Favoriten <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-dropdown">
          <li class="category-animation d-flex"><a href="#">Animation1</a></li>
          <li class="category-animation d-flex"><a href="#">Animation1</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="category">
      <a class="category-name d-flex">Tanzen <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>
      <ul class="category-dropdown">
          <li class="category-animation d-flex"><a href="#">Animation1</a></li>
          <li class="category-animation d-flex"><a href="#">Animation1</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>                   
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```